# C#: Use NUnit to test classes that use Nhibernate

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nhibernate, configuration, nunit

I have a project with a lot of classes that use Nhibernate. Now I want to use NUnit to test those classes. Are there specific things I need to consider?

Answer (score 2):

You can mock NHibernate. The links below might help you:

[Mocking an NHibernate ISession with Moq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828878/mocking-an-nhibernate-isession-with-moq)
[NHibernate testing, mocking ISession](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448405/nhibernate-testing-mocking-isession)

Answer (score 2):

Are you unit testing class mappings i.e. does the data save okay or logic inside the classes?

**Mapping Tests**

I suggest that you use Sqlite and in-memory testing for the hibernate mappings - although this is not technically unit testing. I would create a session on each time you run a test so as you are using the nunit framework use the [SetUp] attribute on a method to tell nunit to run the create session code. Make sure the session is closed and disposed of at the end of the test.

http://support.fluentnhibernate.org/discussions/help/87-in-memory-sqlite-database-for-persistencespecification-testing

**Unit testing**

Unit testing would involve mocking out most of nhibernate so that you were testing the actually classes.

http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/18/mocking-nhibernate.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the session in the begging of (or during) the test....

That's it I guess...

Everything else is the same...

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using NDBUnit.  It allows you to unit test a database while gauranteeing the state of your database is unaltered by external factors.  You can use this along with NUnit to test the class.

Comment: Is ndbunit an extention of nunit? Or is it a stand-alone testing facility? I was also thinking about the nhibernate configuration...

Comment: It is not an extension to NUnit although they do play along nicely.